# Error occurred when installing m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, m2eclipse, galileo

I am using eclipse galileo(Java EE Developers) and i am new to eclipse. I have installed apache-maven-3.1.0-alpha successfully. But when I try to install the m2eclipse, it gives me the following error message.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.1.20130219-1424
 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20130219-1424)
Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.0.20130129-0926 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.3.0.20130129-0926)
 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.resources 3.6.0' but it could not be found
Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.1.20130219-1424 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.3.1.20130219-1424)
 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.resources 3.6.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: Maven POM XML Editor 1.3.1.20130219-1424 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml 1.3.1.20130219-1424)
 To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.3.0,1.4.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.1.20130219-1424 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20130219-1424)
 To: org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml [1.3.1.20130219-1424]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a version as old as Galileo.  Use Juno SR2, or when available, Kepler.